# After enabling NGINX, all posts in WordPress blogs in sub-directories are giving 404 Page Not Found

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url, plesk, permalinks

After I enabled NGINX from Plesk (Web Pro) all my posts in my main and sub-directory blogs give 404 Page Not Found error.

I placed the following code in my "Additional NGINX Directives" in Plesk to fix all the URLS, but it only fixed the main site (example.com) while the sub-directory blogs (example.com/tech/, example.com/mag/ and example.com/dispatch/) are still giving 404 error.

```
# Wordpress Permalinks
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

After that, I removed the code and placed the following one:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($test = PC) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
```

I found this code in one of the [official Plesk pages](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213912945--After-switching-a-WordPress-website-to-FPM-served-by-nginx-in-Plesk-it-fails-to-load-with-404-Not-Found-on-all-pages-except-start-page), and it says:

> If a WordPress installation is located in a subdirectory (for example, "httpdocs/sub-dir") or this is a WordPress multisite network based on subdirectories, add the /sub-dir/ before /index.php?$1 so it will look like this: rewrite ^/(.*)$ /sub-dir/index.php?$1;
> **Note:** For WordPress multisite network based on subfolder, add the above rule for each subdirectory.

As of now I got this (which doesn't work):

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($test = PC) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /tech/index.php?$1;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /mag/index.php?$1;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /dispatch/index.php?$1;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

P.S. The main website works like a charm. In example.com/tech/ and /mag/ and /dispatch/ while the homepages are fine, the posts are giving me a 404 page error.

Comment: have you tried settings->Permalink->save settings?
 this will refresh wordpress rewrite rules.
this might help you as well : https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Comment: Already did, didn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a month of searching I finally found a solution that works great.

First, login into your Plesk (used Plesk for this) and go to your website's **"Apache & nginx Settings"** page. In the **"Additional NGINX Directives"** (modify first) paste the following code:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/tech/(.*)$ /subfolder1/index.php?url=$1 last;
}
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/dispatch/(.*)$ /subfolder2/index.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

subfolder1 and subfolder2 stands for the website's root folder for every sub-directory site.

- **subfolder1** stands for **example.com/subfolder1**
- **subfolder2** stands for **example.com/subfolder2**

etc..

For every subfolder WP site you want to add, just place the following code and change the **subfolder1** with your site's name.

```
 if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite ^/tech/(.*)$ /subfolder1/index.php?url=$1 last;
    }
```

P.S. The converted code needs to be added to the "Additional NGINX Directives".

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new file '.htaccess' via File Manager or upload it to /httpdocs/ or where your files are stored.

file contents:

```html
IndexIgnore * # prevent directory listing
Order deny,allow
Allow from *
# ------------------------------------------ # Rewrite so that php extentions are not shown
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```